# Android Studio Google Cloud Endpoints Run/Debug Config Error

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am a beginner for Android Cloud Endpoints. I am trying to create a backend module in Android Studio 1.0 RC2. Everything seems okay while creating a backend endpoint module (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints). The gradle builds successfully. But when I wanted to debug locally, I found the problem. It said, "App Engine Gradle configuration not detected on module, maybe you need to Sync Project with Gradle".

I tried to rebuild the whole project, it builds successfully. But the error remains.

This is the screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tvuv52ldmr0yzvs/Screen%20Shot%202014-11-27%20at%204.21.14%20pm.png?dl=0

Thank a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This was a recently introduced [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81364) that has since been fixed in Android Studio 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is the solution. But this is what I did. I created another new project (the problem happened in existing project that I migrated from Android Studio 0.8.9 to 1.0 RC2. I added new module for Google Cloud EndPoints. Initially it was same problem (there is same error in debug config as above, although it can build the whole project successfully.) But after I changed the build.gradle file in backend module to gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.17 (latest), the new project backend was okay.

> dependencies {
>           classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.17'
>       }
>
> dependencies {
>       appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.17'
>
> ```
> compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.17'
> compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.17'
> compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5' }
> ```

I tried to change the build.gradle file in my migrated projects, but still failed. So, what I did was copy the content from new project

> backend.iml

file into my migrated project backend.iml. And it works.